# thread in for loop!! unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating thread in for loop, as per iteration one thread is get created. In this thread I am calling a method that take path from array of paths. When I run it debug mode step by step thread call the method with each path from the array of paths. but when I run it normally, the thread call the method with unexpected paths. Some time it take same paths 2 times and sometimes same path used all time.

What is the issue with code? I run the code without thread it runs perfectly but only in thread the problem goes.

Here is the code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < appConfigDataPath.Length; i++)
 {
      var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
      string serverPath = appConfigDataPath[i];
      string serverName = appConfigDataName[i];

      var threadSplit = new Thread(() =>
                 {
                     ScanProcess(serverPath, serverName);
                     handle.Set();
                 });
      threadSplit.Start();
      waitHandles[i] = handle;
 }
```

Comment: You should set the IsBackgroundThread property to true. More importantly, use the threads from the ThreadPool or use Parallel Tasks to get better performance.

Comment: That only is the problem. I resticted to use thread pool or parallel for.... I have to do it with normal threads

Comment: What does `ScanProcess` do? Does it use the arrays?

Comment: have you tried using a distinct value int variable inside the loop, int x = i; then using the variable x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is serverPath is changed before ScanProcess is actually called.

1. serverPath=path0
2. startThread0
3. serverPath=path1
4. thread0:ScanProcess(serverPath,..), serverPath is already path1
5. startThread1
6. thread1:ScanProcess(serverPath,..), serverPath is still path1

You need to pass the values in through the Start function as a copy.
try this:

```
class Data
{
  public string Path;
  public string Name;
  public EventWaitHandle Handle;
  public Data (string path, string name, EventWaitHandle handle)
  {
     Path = path;
     Name = name;
     Handle = handle;
  }
}


var threadSplit = new Thread((obj) =>
{
  Data data = obj as Data;
  ScanProcess(data.Path, data.Name);
  data.Handle.Set();
});
threadSplit.Start(new Data(serverPath, serverName, handle));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define distinct, local variables to hold your path information in each iteration of the loop. The problem is due to the nature of 'closures' when using Lambda expressions with external variables, as you are here.

If you declare `serverPath` and `serverName` locally, within the loop instead of externally, it should work as expected.

Comment: +1, but the OP edited his question to show those variables declared locally. But the original code is probably what he was running.

Comment: @Josh Einstein - looks to me like *maybe* he edited the code to try that, and it didn't work. At least, that's what I'm going with, to be polite! I think we need to see the impl. of that method though.

Answer (score 0):

Your *serverPath* and *serverName* are in the outer scope of your thread closure. You should make them *local*. Declaring them inside the loop scope will resolve this issue.

Comment: @GAPS: Weird. Did you try to put `threadSplit.Start();` in the end of the loop? If it won't work either, you should show us the implementation of `ScanProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure who is using the waitHandles array...but try moving the assignment.....

```
var threadSplit = new Thread(() =>
{
  ScanProcess(serverPath, serverName);
  handle.Set();
});
waitHandles[i] = handle;  // assign handle before starting thread.
threadSplit.Start();
```

Edit: And as others noticed (bleck...I missed them) serverPath, serverName and handle must be local.